# How to convert text to css

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to make a download page for a project that lets you download text files and it has to be as short as possible.

**Code**

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="?"><a><button>Download</button></a>
/* ignore the href for now
```

**CSS I’m trying to add**

```
body {
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
}
button:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

**link in browser**

`data:text/html, <link rel="stylesheet" href="?"><a><button>Download</button></a> <a href="data:application/base64,TEXTINFILE" download="FILENAME.txt"><button>download</button></a>`

---

I’m trying to add some css however it can’t be part of the link since it will be too long.

I tried using pastebin but it didn’t work because it uses `text/plain` Instead of `text/css`. I also tried using media fire by using the download link, but it still wouldn’t work.

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what you're trying to do, or what you're asking.
I can see you've put in some effort, yet some things just don't make sense.

What is "link in browser"?
What do you mean "it will be too long"...
What "has to be as short as possible" mean?

Please provide more details and clarify your question, then we will gladly try to help

Comment: Link in browser is… the link that you would put in your web browser. “It would be too long” means that the link would be way to long. “Short as possible” means the link has to be short as possible. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you would have to explain it better, so people can understand your question.

Comment: Please add a code snippet showing your issue

Comment: I’m new to stack and I don’t know how to add a code snipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my hackaround. Try to copy this data URL:

`data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<title>Document</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gistcdn.githack.com/naruaika/5ec023686c2ff4e0e5a00be6bd35427e/raw/449176739776a435591cad901188af924e61d1c3/text-red.css"><body><p class="text-red">This is a red text ...</p><p>This is a black text ...</p>`

which is equivalent to:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gistcdn.githack.com/naruaika/5ec023686c2ff4e0e5a00be6bd35427e/raw/449176739776a435591cad901188af924e61d1c3/text-red.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="text-red">This is a red text ...</p>
        <p>This is a black text ...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**

We could use, for instance, the GitHub Gist to put the CSS on the internet: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/naruaika/5ec023686c2ff4e0e5a00be6bd35427e/raw/449176739776a435591cad901188af924e61d1c3/text-red.css,

which contains:

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

Then we could use raw.githack.com, that'll solve the Header problems, and put it as href: https://gistcdn.githack.com/naruaika/5ec023686c2ff4e0e5a00be6bd35427e/raw/449176739776a435591cad901188af924e61d1c3/text-red.css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Is the CSS to style the elements on the page or the downloaded content?

If it is the former then in the `head` Element you can add a link to the .css file that is on your file system. The file path should be relative from your .html file to the .css

This will also be served by the web server as and when the application is deployed

Comment: I tried putting it in head but it still work. If you want to check it out for yourself here is the link: `data:text/html,<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://download1078.mediafire.com/yw3ri6y3edsg/hkkksa2mn01kpvi/style.css"></head><a href="data:application/base64,TEXTINFILE" download="FILENAME.txt"><button>download</button></a>`

Comment: I would set up a codepen or gist to show what you have already to be able to advise more

Comment: Here is the code pen https://codepen.io/AnotherRandomCoder/pen/mdpWWgQ